# YCM on windows vim can't find python

Tags: windows-10, vim, python, gvim, vim-plugins

I would like to be able to use YouCompleteMe plugin on vim (on windows).
I have installed vundle, and followed the installation guide for YCM on Windows. When I run `:PluginInstall` I see:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 16, in    File
> "C:\Users\ryan.vim\bundle\YouCompleteMe\python\ycm\base.py", line 21,
> in  
> from ycm import vimsupport, paths   File "C:\Users\ryan.vim\bundle\YouCompleteMe\python\ycm\vimsupport.py",
> line 24, in 
> from ycmd.utils import ( ByteOffsetToCodepointOffset,   File "C:\Users\ryan.vim\bundle\YouCompleteMe\third_party\ycmd\ycmd\utils.py",
> line 22, in 
> import socket   File "C:\Users\ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\socket.py",
> li ne 51, in 
> import _socket ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_socket' YouCompleteMe unavailable: No module named '_socket'

I have python 2.7.16, 3.10.4, and 3.11.1 installed.

When I run `:version`, I see:

```
MS-Windows 64-bit GUI version with OLE support
```

In features I see:

```
+python/dyn
+python3/dyn
```

When I run `:py print('hello')` I get

> E887: Sorry, this command is disabled, the Python's site module could
> not be loaded.

When I run `:py3 print('hello')` I get hello back.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure of the root cause, but I was able to solve this by setting the PYTHONPATH environment variable.  This is what mine is, for example:

```
C:\>set PYTHONPATH
PYTHONPATH=C:\python311\DLLs;C:\python311\Lib
```